# Why it show defer as async and async as defer? Get "dom parsed event" right! But there are no?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, web-performance

I have a loader and want to study async and defer timings. It is an external script tag dynamically inserted - No inline defer.

At first I had a fight with understanding why *async behaved as defer - it executed after DOMContentLoaded*.

With 2000 DOM elements the async started show it can execute before DOMContentLoaded. It loaded from local drive. With fetch from host it makes more sense to execute scripts async while waiting for response. So that works.

Then I changed to test defer and surprice.. Now I fight with the joke why **defer behaves as async - executing before DOMContentLoaded** !

With 100000 DOM elements that took over 30s the script execution still happened before DOMContentLoaded. What is wrong?

Here is the relevant parts I tested with ...

**loader.js**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
});


  var s = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
//  s.async = true; s.defer = false;
  s.async = false; s.defer = true;
  s.src = "script.js"
  console.log("Fetch script");
```

**script.js**

```
console.log("Execute script");
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>  window.ti = performance.now() </script>

    --- put here every html you can find ---

    <script>
      var n = document.getElementsByTagName('*').length
      var t = parseInt(performance.now() - ti) / 1000
      document.write("<br>Parsed " + n + " elements in " + t + " s ")
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Console in FF and Chrome**

```
Fetch script
Execute script
DOMContentLoaded
```

**A deferred script never should execute before DOM is ready to be used**.
Now we have a case where DOMContentLoaded fires before DOM is out on screen. How?

---

**Edit #1**

Beware DOMContentLoaded - I wanted "dom content parsed" !!!
(so that was the bug in the code - or in my mind)
A correction (thanks to Pointy) - in my words...

*Deferred scripts is executed after dom has parsed, but dom is still loading.. When deferred scripts and eventual events is done the DOMContentLoaded fires.*

So it is some kind of "DOMContent**Parsed**" that I need. The best I found is *readystatechange event* and *document.readyState*...

Let's extend loader.js with this line:

```
s.onload = function(){ console.log(document.readyState) }
```

With enough of dom it shows in both Chrome and Firefox console:

```
Fetch script
Execute script
loading
DOMContentLoaded
```

That means a defer script executes while [DOM is loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)!
Yes yes - it is loading, until DOMContentLoaded. Shame that readyState not tell WHEN dom is parsed! I also tried..

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  console.log(">>" + document.readyState); 
});
```

This don't fire on "loading" because it already has fired, but it say "interactive" AFTER defer scripts loaded and say "complete" where DOMContentLoaded is (are they same?) and it has not more to say.

I have no more idéa of a method or event that trigger at/when dom parsed. It has to be before continuing loading other dom stuff, to get a correct timing mark before other timings!

There is nothing more to find! There is nothing more before the first point in [Living Standard — Last Updated 15 April 2019](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end) section 12.2.7 The end (even title joking with me): *It is the readystatechange that should do "interactive" **before** any scripts, but it practically does not*. Why?

For me it seem to be that readyState has a bug on a local index.html bigger than 2000 elements, because I can execute a deferred script before it say "interactive". It is now definitely clear when putting that readyState in the script too (i forgot) and it says "loading", that means a big html is still loading while this executes:

script.js

```
console.log("Execute script " + document.readyState);
```

**Conclusion**: *Sometimes defer behaves as async, and async as defer*

Comment: With enough html... In console I see "Execute script" and on the next line "loading", so that means Chrome run s.defer = true; s.async = false; despite DOM is loading!!! Tested on two computers. Defer is async in Chrome but not FF

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `defer` attribute on [the MDN page for script elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.

What you're seeing is the intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer! Is there an event for "document has been parsed"?

Comment: Well because of how `defer` works, the fact that your script is in fact running effectively means that the document has been parsed. You can verify that by creating a script with `defer`, and have it check for an element with some id that you place right at the very end of the `<body>`.  If your script finds that element with `.getElementById()`, then know the document has been parsed.

Comment: There is an early event for "interactive" but neither this was done before "Execute script": document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() { console.log(document.readyState); });